# bootstrap fileupload - Open browsedialog on click input field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use the bootstrap fileinput with the first Example
http://plugins.krajee.com/file-basic-usage-demo

Givs a way, that the browse dialog not only open when I click "browse"? In normal HTML I can click into the input field and the browse dialog open too

Comment: Show what you did in the code. And refer [ask] before questioning here.

Comment: The Code is the same from Example1: <input id="input-1" type="file" class="file">